# How can I add a variable to this bash command?

Tags: ssh

```
ssh $server_gd_bare -t "cd  ~/public_html; git pull -q ~/root.git master"
```

I want to add these two varialbes to the command line above but ..

```
working_repo = ~/public_html

root_repo = ~/root.git master
```

Note that I am sshing into my remote server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just define the variables and use them in the substitution for the respective parts of the code as below:

```
server_gd_bare="some-server"
working_repo="~/public_html"
root_repo="~/root.git master"

ssh $server_gd_bare -t "cd  $working_repo; git pull -q $root_repo"
```